# How to implement delay that can be cancelled?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have a windows service that is responsible for listening JMS messages. I am giving a simplified version of implementation details. As messages arrive they are handed over for processing to a different Task (thread) and limit a max number of tasks with the help of BlockingCollection. There is a retry mechanism in place to retry until the processing is successful with some amount of delay between each retry or max retry attempts are exhausted. The reason for retry mechanism is to cope with issues in Legacy applications that consume these messages. Legacy systems are built using Pessimistic locking and sometimes the processing of message runs into errors, which eventually goes thru after few retry attempts. Due to cost benefit analysis, it was decided not to address the issues in Legacy systems as those applications will be replaced in 2 to 3 years.

This retry mechanism runs on the same task thread that is responsible for handling the processing of message. Initially I used Thread.Sleep to introduce delay between each retry attempt. It worked, but when I try to shutdown the windows service, it is taking longer if there are messages currently being processed and waiting to be retried.

I then went on an adventure of implementing a way to cancel the waiting mechanism if a shutdown event was triggered.

I used two different approaches.

**Option #1**
One using ManualResetEvent and when I have to wait I have following code in place (posting only relevant code blocks)

```
private readonly ManualResetEvent _lockEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

if (_lockEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(120000)))
{
    Log.Info($"Thread interrupted. Retrying will resume after windows service restarts for message id {messageId}");
    return;
}
```

When a shutdown event occurs, I cancel the cancellationTokenSource and set the ManualResetEvent. Everything appears to do what I want. Its just that I have to do two operations so that any code that depends on CancellationToken know to gracefully cancel and also gracefully break the retry waiting.

```
_subscriberCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
_lockEvent.Set();
```

**Option #2**
After upgrading to .Net 4.6, I started using Task type wherever I can. I realized, I could use Task to implement a delay as well, so here is a simplified version of code that I tried

```
private void WaitBeforeRetrying(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var waitingTask = Task.Delay(120000, cancellationToken);
    waitingTask.Wait(cancellationToken);
}
```

Where ever I need delay, I just invoke the method by passing a CancellationToken

```
WaitBeforeRetrying(SubscriberCancellationToken);
```

When a shutdown event occurs, I simply invoke cancel on CancellationTokenSource and everything shuts down gracefully.

```
_subscriberCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
```

Both Option 1 and Option 2 appears to be doing the job.

Are there any drawbacks for Option 2 over Option 1? Any other better option than what I have so far? Really appreciate any input.

**UPDATE**
After reading the comments from @EricLippert, I understood what I was doing wrong. Most of my threads were going into a waiting state instead of actually doing any productive work. It was the result of sprinkling few asynchronous calls in the synchronous workflow.

I now modified my delay method as follows

```
private async Task WaitBeforeRetrying(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.Delay(120000, cancellationToken);
}
```

And I invoke it as

```
await WaitBeforeRetrying(SubscriberCancellationToken);
```

And then refactored rest of the code to propagate async mechanism all the way to the top layer. It not only helped to easily cancel the delay if I don't have to wait, but also prevented the threads to be in a blocked state unnecessarily. Really appreciate every ones feedback.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but both options are bad. You go to all the trouble of setting up an asynchronous delay and then you synchronously wait it! That is a very strange thing to do. And you've conflated tasks with threads, which is like saying that there's no difference between a to-do list that says "mow the lawn", and a person who mows lawns. Those are very different things. But worse: in your case the job you're giving your worker is "do nothing for ten minutes".  You don't need to hire a worker for that!

Comment: Thank you @EricLippert for the clarification. So are you suggesting for me to consider implementing async await pattern thru the entire call chain?

Comment: The point of an await is to be able to execute other work while you are asynchronously waiting; synchronously blocking on the task produced by an async method is working against the entire point of await. If you intend to synchronously wait for the result, then why asynchronously wait at all? It doesn't make any sense. But wait, it gets worse...

Comment: ...Consider this workflow:  create a task representing an asynchronous fetching a string from a URL. After the task completes, close the connection to the web site. OK, so we have a task, and its continuation, represented by awaiting the task before the continuation. If the task is not complete when it is created then we return *another* task to the caller.  Now suppose we *synchronously* block on *that* task.  What happens?  When the network layer asynchronously completes it sends a message to the now-blocked thread saying to run the completion of the task!

Comment: But the thread is blocked, so it cannot process the message, which means that the *outer* task can never complete because the continuation of the *inner* task cannot run. When you do this kind of stuff you immediately create deadlocks *even if there is only one thread involved*.  Remember, networking I/O hardware runs at a level *below* that of operating system threads.

Comment: You've created a workflow where you've said (1) put the bread in the toaster, (2) if the toast is not ready, go to the next step, but don't forget to put jam on the toast after it is ready, (3) go to sleep and don't wake up until the jam is on the toast. If you did that workflow in real life then you'd sleep forever, because *you'd be asleep when it was time to put the jam on the toast*.

Comment: @EricLippert, Appreciate all the feedback. It really helped me understand the gaps and potential side effects. I have added an Update to my original post based on all the information. I monitored the total thread count for my process and the count is lower than what it used to be previously.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think they're any different. The effect of both is that the thread is blocked until the time runs out.

If you're using this in ASP.NET, then blocking threads is not a good thing. In that case, you can make your method `async` and use `await Task.Delay`. That'll resume the code after the delay, but allow the thread to work on other things in the mean time.

```
private async Task WaitBeforeRetrying(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.Delay(120000, cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel Luci , What you suggested not only works in ASP.NET, but also in other type of projects.

Comment: True. It's just more important with ASP.NET since it runs on a limited number of threads.